# my table is not getting created in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new to wordpress , I am creating the table but I dont know where is the error occuring , hence table is not creating in database , my table code is below

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "myuser";
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREAMENT NOT NULL ,
        `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
         `email` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
      ) $charset_collate; ";
```

and I am inserting data in it but there is no error showing neither the table is creating

```
 $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "myuser";

    $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name, //table
            array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email), //data
            array('%s', '%s') //data format         
    );
    $message.="Users added successfully";
```

Comment: This code only defines the sql query, it does not execute anything yet. Could you include the part of the code where you're executing the sql? (If this is all the code, the answer would be that you're not executing the query, btw)

Comment: I think you are talking about sql query to insert data which I have include please check the code again

Comment: No, Stratadox is right. We need to see _how_ you're running the SQL query that creates the table. Please post some more code.

Comment: Also, you have a typo there: `AUTO_INCREAMENT` should be `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: yeah I corrected it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've only defined the sql query yet, you still need to execute it.

According to [this article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table) you can use the following code:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
dbDelta($sql);
```

Just put it right after the part that starts with `$sql =`.

Assuming you're writing some kind of plugin, notice you'll also have to add the function as `register_activation_hook`.

For more information, see [Writing a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) and [Creating Tables with Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins).